# Determining the length of a vector which is part of a right angled triangle.

Tags: vectors

ABC is a right angled triangle with the right angle at B. If the vector from A to C is equal to 2i+4j and the vector from A to B is parallel to i+j, find the vector from A to B.

I'm relatively new to vector algebra and I've been on this problem all afternoon, I know BC•BA=0, but I can't get much further and would really appreciate a push in the right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

- Since $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is parallel to $\vec\imath + \vec\jmath$, it is obvious that $\overrightarrow{AB} = a\vec\imath + a\vec\jmath$ for some $a\ne 0$.
- $\overrightarrow{AC} = \overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC}$

Solving this and $\overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{BC} = 0$ together should give you the value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up from @kenntm's answer. Let $\overrightarrow{AB} = a(\textbf{i} + \textbf{j})$ and $\overrightarrow{BC} = x\textbf{i} + y\textbf{j}$

The first condition is the right angle, should give

$$ \overrightarrow{AB}\cdot\overrightarrow{BC} = ax + ay = 0 $$

The second condition is that $A$, $B$ and $C$ form a triangle, which should give two equations

$$ \overrightarrow{AB} + \overrightarrow{BC} = \overrightarrow{BC} $$ 
$$ \Rightarrow (a+x)\textbf{i} + (a+y)\textbf{j} = 2\textbf{i} + 4\textbf{j} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \left\{ \begin{matrix} a + x = 2 \\ a + y = 4 \end{matrix} \right. $$

Solving these equations together will give you the values of $a$, $x$ and $y$